# Lifetime relationship between function arguments and return value

Tags: rust

### Question 1

What are the differences between these two functions in rust?

```
fn foo<'a>(x: &'a i32) -> &'a i32 {
    x
}
fn foo<'a: 'b, 'b>(x: &'a i32) -> &'b i32 {
    x
}
```

### Question 2

What constraints are provided when the same lifetime parameter `'a` is used among multiple function parameters and also in the return value?

```
fn foo<'a>(x: &'a i32, y: &'a i32) -> &'a i32 {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 

Two differences as far as I can tell:

- The second has two lifetimes that can be different, the first has only one.
- The second's lifetimes are [early-bound](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/early-late-bound.html),the first's is late-bound. There are some differences, the main one being that you can't create a HRTB function pointer with early bound lifetime (`let f: fn(&i32) -> &i32 = foo2;` does not compile).

You almost always want (1), since it is less verbose and allows HRTB.

2.

The lifetime is the smallest of all. Ignoring the points at question 1, this is the same as:

```rust
fn foo<'a, 'b: 'a, 'c: 'a>(x: &'b i32, y: &'c i32) -> &'a i32 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @user4815162342 Oops, that was a mistake, I meant (1).